# How to constantly change a iframe?

Tags: php, html, iframe

How can I create a piece of code that other people can use, that is an iframe, but on the users site, the iframe keeps changing... So like ads, I want to give users a piece of code that they can implement into their site and that iframekeeps changing to different ads.

Comment: `<iframe src="http://example.com/the_page_on_your_server"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Use a timer with JavaScript. For example, every 30 seconds, reload the page in the iframe.
2. Use AJAX on the main page. This way you really don't need an iframe. All you need is the HTTP Request through JavaScript.

With either method, you'll use PHP for example to reload the page with new ads.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks itsols, but how do I do that? Are eir links I can I have pls?